# Pandas & Datetime - Specific sequence of hours but changing the dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I got this date range:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

date = '2020-09-01 10:00:00'
date_range = pd.date_range(date, freq='60min', periods=5)
```

Out:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-09-01 10:00:00', '2020-09-01 11:00:00',
               '2020-09-01 12:00:00', '2020-09-01 13:00:00',
               '2020-09-01 14:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='60T')
```

I want to keep follow this specific sequence of hours but changing the dates for an year.
Something like that:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-09-01 10:00:00', '2020-09-01 11:00:00',
               '2020-09-01 12:00:00', '2020-09-01 13:00:00',
               '2020-09-01 14:00:00', '2020-09-02 10:00:00',
               '2020-09-02 11:00:00', '2020-09-02 12:00:00',
               '2020-09-02 13:00:00', '2020-09-02 14:00:00'
                '...', '2021-09-01 10:00:00',
               '2021-09-01 11:00:00', '2021-09-01 12:00:00',
               '22021-09-01 13:00:00', '2021-09-01 14:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='60T')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two `date_range`:

```
date = "2020-09-01 10:00:00"

date_range = list()
for dt in pd.date_range(date, periods=365, freq="D"):
    date_range += pd.date_range(dt, freq="60min", periods=5)
```